# Return ordered subset of values from dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, dictionary

I've this dictionary

`people = {'people': [{'name': 'Christina Koch', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Alexander Skvortsov', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Luca Parmitano', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Andrew Morgan', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Oleg Skripochka', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Jessica Meir', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 6, 'message': 'success'}`

I need to get just the names, such as:

```
    Alexander Skvortsov
    Alexey Ovchinin
    Andrew Morgan
    Christina Koch
    Luca Parmitano
    Nick Hague
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does not work? SO is not a code factory, where you can ask for people to write your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
d = {'people': [{'name': 'Christina Koch', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Alexander Skvortsov', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Luca Parmitano', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Andrew Morgan', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Oleg Skripochka', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Jessica Meir', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 6, 'message': 'success'}

for p in d['people']:
    print(p['name'])
```

Or if you want the results in a list, alphabetically sorted:

```
name_list = sorted([p['name'] for p in d['people']])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
d = {'people': [{'name': 'Christina Koch', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Alexander Skvortsov', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Luca Parmitano', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Andrew Morgan', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Oleg Skripochka', 'craft': 'ISS'}, {'name': 'Jessica Meir', 'craft': 'ISS'}], 'number': 6, 'message': 'success'}

for name in sorted([person['name'] for person in d['people']]):
  print(name)
```